# How to update an NSManagedObject whenever a specific attribute is changed?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

Imagine I have a Core Data object, Product. Each Product has a `quantity`, `price`, and `total` attribute. Total is there for efficiency when retrieving items from the table. (I understand that there may be an efficient way to get the computed value using fetched properties, but this is only an example, and that answer is not what I am looking for.)

```
+------+----------+-------+-------+
| Name | Quantity | Price | Total |
+------+----------+-------+-------+
| Foo  |        1 |    20 |    20 |
| Bar  |        0 |    30 |     0 |
| Baz  |        3 |     5 |    15 |
+------+----------+-------+-------+
```

Assume that the `price` of a product never changes. However, the `quantity` does change. Whenever the `quantity` changes, I would like to be notified so that I can recompute the `total`. I would like to avoid using KVO if possible because I have a custom NSManagedObject class, `product`, and I would like to override one of its methods in order to update the price and not have to worry about registering/unregistering for notifications on its own attributes.

This method should only be called when the price is changed, not every time any of the attributes on the object has changed.

I would also like this method to be triggered right when the value is changed (e.g. not right before the context is saved), so that I can access the new `total` attribute before the context is saved.

Which method should I override and can it be done in a category on my Product class?

---

Note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901207/detecting-changes-to-a-specific-attribute-of-nsmanagedobject) is similar but is mainly concerned with running more than one thread, which may require more complicated answers. I am looking for something simple, on a single thread.

Comment: But TechZen's answer to that question is (as I think) exactly what you need: A custom setter for the `quantity` property that would update both "quantity" and "total". (Very simple, no threads :-)

Comment: @Martin: TechZen's answer seems to refer to Xcode 3, that copy option is no longer available in Xcode 4.

Comment: But you still can override the accessor methods for your managed object subclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the setter method for the `quantity` attribute of your entity:

```
- (void)setQuantity:(NSNumber *)quantity
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"quantity"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:quantity forKey:@"quantity"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"quantity"];

    NSNumber *price = ... // compute new price
    self.price = price;
}
```

You can add that code to a category of the Product class if you don't want to change
the Xcode generated files.

Comment: To know which boiler plate code to use, see [Managed Object Accessor Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154).