# "Core Data could not fulfill a fault" for objects that were not deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, crash, fault

For a recent update to an app, I am seeing many crash logs with the error that core data could not fulfill a fault. But nowhere in the app (startup, or elsewhere) did I delete the objects whose faults cannot be fulfilled, nor would they have been cascade deleted. How else can this error be happening? And is there a way to catch it and fix it within the live app?

Could it also be if you added but did not properly save the object yet?

Comment: Does your app use fetched results controller? If yes, are you specifying any cache during its creation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265115/core-data-could-not-fulfill-a-fault-error

Comment: Are you using thread confinement or queue confinement? Is this happening in the same context or different contexts? Are you invoking performBlockAndWait: at any point?

Comment: @quellish This is happening in the same context. I am not familiar with thread confinement and queue confinement, I will look those up. I am performing nested blocks and objects are created in those blocks.

Comment: @Suhas I am using fetched results controller. I am not specifying a cache during its creation.

Comment: @Leijonien this is not a general "core data could not fulfill a fault" question but more specifically focused on objects that were not deleted, and the question you mentioned pointed to one solution that had to do with KVO, which i am not using, and then the general guide on this error, which implies to me that the object must have been deleted - which is the very basis of my question, because it was not

Comment: @JPK Sounds like it is trying to fufil a fault for an object that has not been saved yet. Are you doing something that is causing the object you have created but not saved to become a fault? I would also recommend using multiple contexts per the documentation - a new context for every set of changes you are making. In your case this would probably mean making a new child context from your current context, and within that context only saving one level up. This example may be helpful: https://github.com/quellish/QueuedCoreData

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that an object that was not "properly" saved to cause this behaviour.

One way to do that is:

- Insert an object in a child context
- obtain a permanent ID for that object
- save to the parent context
- obtain the object in the parent context
- refresh the object in the parent context
- access the object in the parent context (fulfil a fault for that object)

**Edit:**

Another way to reach this state in a single context architecture is:

- Insert an object
- obtain a permanent id for the object
- refresh the object
- try and access the object (trigger a fault on the object)

the refresh might be a result of a fetched results controller paging through the data and not necessarily something "visible" in your application.

In addition, there is a CoreData "bug" that not always allows you to catch this exception in a parent-child context architecture, but you can try ...

However, if this is the scenario you encounter, this is not a desired behaviour for your application. you are loosing the new data added to the store.

Comment: I think this is what is happening but I cannot understand why, since I technically only use the app delegate's managed object context to save objects. How could an extra context have been created?

Comment: And how can I now go back to user's data and move all the objects created in the lost context to the parent context?

Comment: This scenario only happen in a multi-context environment. I've added another scenario, see my edit.

Comment: @DanShelly Another cause to add to your answer - save failure in a parent context due to merge conflict. Then trying to access the object after refreshing it. Fun fun fun.

Comment: @DanShelly can I mistakenly create a new context while I am using blocks?

Comment: Are you allocating one in your blocks `[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init...]`? are you setting a parent context anywhere?

Comment: @DanShelly No, I think I found the problem. I WAS creating an object on a background thread! But what is funny is that is not the object that I am getting the message for, although it is an object that can be related to the object created on the background thread through another object. Should that be happening? Even though I made this mistake with one object, why am I getting the error for multiple objects?

Comment: @DanShelly thank you so much, I accepted your answer; if you do get a chance to still answer my above question, it would help me out a lot today, and I think it is also related to the overall question asked. thanks either way!

Comment: created a new question because the above is actually a different, though related, question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006689/core-data-could-not-fulfill-a-fault-for-objects-that-were-created-in-the-appde