# "Core Data could not fulfill a fault" for objects that were created in the appDelegate managedObjectContext on the main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, fault

I mistakenly created a group of objects on a background thread, which created a new managedObjectContext in which the objects were saved.

This resulted in numerous "Core Data could not fulfill a fault" crashes in my live app. Please note - I am not trying to delete these objects - it is a problem with the way they were created, when I try to save them again afterwards in the app delegate (main) context on the main thread.

The thing that is confusing is that I am seeing this error for other objects, objects of a different type. They can be related to the objects created in the background thread, though they themselves were not created in the in the background thread.

I am confused as to how this could have happened. How could I get the "Core Data could not fulfill a fault" error for an object not created in the background thread, but the app delegate (main) context?

And is there any way at all to go back and fix this mistake in the live apps of my users?

Let me reference my other question, through which I discovered this error:
["Core Data could not fulfill a fault" for objects that were not deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994482/core-data-could-not-fulfill-a-fault-for-objects-that-were-not-deleted)

I wrote up a new question because I feel that it is a different issue - though most definitely related.

Here is the code that created the objects in the background thread:

```
- (void)friendPickerViewControllerDidChooseFriends:(NSArray *)friends {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__
    if (friends.count > 0) {
        [[FacebookHelper sharedManager] friendPickerController].navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;


        [self startProgressIndicator];
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(importFriends:) withObject:friends];
    }
    else {
        [self dismissModalImportViewControllerAnimated];//releases picker delegates, etc
    }
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Import Friend
- (void)importFriends:(NSArray*)friends {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *friend in friends) {

        [self importFriend:friend withCompletion:^(void){

            CGFloat friendNumber = [friends indexOfObject:friend]+1;
            CGFloat friendCount = friends.count;
            self.importProgress = friendNumber/friendCount;
        }];
    }
}

- (void)importFriend:(NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>*)friend withCompletion:( void (^) (void) )completionBlock {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__
    Person *myNewPerson = [GetObjectArrayHelper createNewPersonMocSaveNew:YES];

    myNewPerson.facebookID = friend.id;
    myNewPerson.facebookName = friend.name;

    NSString *nameFirst = [friend.first_name stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSString *nameLast = [friend.last_name stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


    NSString *imageID = friend.id;
    UIImage *pickedImage = nil;
    if(imageID){
        pickedImage = [FacebookHelper imageForObject:imageID];
    }

    DLog(@"pickedImage:%@",pickedImage);

    if(pickedImage){
        [self setImagesForFacebookImage:pickedImage forPerson:myNewPerson];
    }

    //we should ALWAYS have a name
    [Helper changePerson:myNewPerson firstName:nameFirst lastName:nameLast];

    if(completionBlock) {
        completionBlock();
    }
}


- (void)finishedImporting {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__
    [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:[self completeString]];
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissModalImportViewControllerAnimated) withObject:nil afterDelay:SV_PROGRESS_HUD_SUCCESS_DELAY];
}

- (void)dismissModalImportViewControllerAnimated {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__

    [Helper mocSave];//THIS SAVES IN THE APP DELEGATE MANAGED OBJECT CONTEXT -

    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){

        [[FacebookHelper sharedManager] friendPickerController].delegate = nil;
        [[FacebookHelper sharedManager] friendPickerController].navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }];
}
```

Please note that the objects that I am concerned about are not any of the objects created here (or in methods called here), but objects that later become associated with these objects.

Why are THEY "Core Data could not fulfill a fault" crash? (I understand why any object created here or in a method called here would get it).

Also - once I figure out why this mess happened (and fix the code that caused it) I need to fix the rogue objects in my users' live apps. I could really use some advise on that as well!

Comment: Could you add the code that create the objects and the crash? what is your context architecture (parent-child, merge, detached)? were the related objects on the main context deleted?

Comment: Please give a little more detail about how your code works. Specifically: (a) you have more than one managed object context-- are they related by a parent/child relationship? (b) When you save "again", how *exactly* are you doing this? Post relevant code.

Comment: @DanShelly I definitely would add the code that created the crash but it is sprinkled throughout the app - Numerous objects are crashing all over the place, in different view controllers and different methods! I will add the code the created the main objects - it is code that imports facebook friends on a background thread - creating a Person object for each facebook friend that is imported. It also creates other related objects - but the objects that it does NOT create are the ones that I am concerned about, when trying to access them causes this error.

Comment: @TomHarrington I did not *intentionally* create more than one managedObjectContext. I did it by importing on the wrong thread - the background thread - when EVERYTHING else I do in the app is on the main thread, and in the appdelegate moc.

Comment: *"I did not intentionally create more than one managedObjectContext. I did it by importing on the wrong thread"*. That sentence makes no sense. Managed object contexts don't get created unless you create one. Using different threads does not automatically cause new contexts to exist.

Comment: I never intentionally created another context. I always use the app delegate context throughout the app. Yet I did create these objects on the background thread and then saved the app delegate context. In addition to the 'fulfill a fault' error I am also seeing the 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship between objects in different contexts'. I never intentionally create another context so how is this happening?

Comment: @DanShelly just read the last part of your question - no objects were deleted, and I only use the appdelegate's managedObjectContext throughout the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question and your comments, you are:

- Using a single managed object on multiple threads.
- Not taking any precautions to deal with the fact that `NSManagedObjectContext` is not thread safe.

As a result, you are getting weird, confusing crashes.

This is exactly what one would expect in this situation. Using a managed object context on more than one thread without taking precautions is essentially a recipe for crashes and confusion. These crashes may not make a lot of sense, because you're corrupting the context's internal state.

If you want to use a context on more than one thread, you *must* use one of the queue confinement options (`NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` or `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`) and then you *must* put all code that uses the context or any object fetched from them in a `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`. (Exception: if you use `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and you know your code is on the main thread, you may just use the context directly). You might also use your own locking mechanism via something like `NSLock`, but come on, threading is already hard enough for most people.

It's generally better to use one context per thread, either as parent/child contexts or as independent contexts, but the approach above also works.

If you've actually managed to save bogus objects as a result of this, the only real recourse is to fetch those objects and either fix them up or delete them. How to identify these objects depends on your data model-- there's no universal test for "is this object crap?". Any checks depend on what your app considers to be correct.

Comment: Thanks Tom. You are right on. It was actually a mistake made very late one night when I was really tired. I NEVER intended to use multiple threads :( So when I fetch the objects, is there a way to tell that they were created on the background thread vs. the main thread? Otherwise how do I know they are bad, since I created them with all of the data that I want them to have? Also - what about those objects that were NOT created on the background thread - is it normal that I am getting this error for them too, simply because I have royally screwed up ALL OF MY USERS' DATA??

Comment: And - could the mistake I made also yield crashes with the error:'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship between objects in different contexts'

Comment: The objects don't record what thread they were created on. That's not relevant to a data model (or shouldn't be). Like I said, you'll have to figure out what differentiates "good" from "bad" data according to your app's needs, and use that. They're not bad unless they contain bad data, but only you can say what data is bad. As for other errors, once you start corrupting your context, confusing or nonsensical errors are not much of a surprise.

Comment: Thanks Tom - so, maybe - *possibly* - once the app shuts down and starts back up again, things could be in an okay state? (provided of course that the error doesn't happen again)

Comment: And what I mean by that, is that the user might have tried to do something and it crashed because of the state of the objects so they couldn't; but after closing down the app and restarting, the objects might be in a workable state - does that make sense?

Comment: They could be, but it's hard to predict. It depends on when the app crashed, whether changes were successfully saved before crashing, and whether trouble started before or after the save.